# Jquery transfer name attribute to child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to transfer the `name` attribute of an element 2 generations up. The reason is, I'm using a [jquery plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) that gives `<select>` elements a dropdown with images. It uses jquery that converts something like this:

```
<select id="fruitselect" name="fruit">
    <option data-description="It's red" >Apple</option>
    <option data-description="It's yellow" >Banana</option>
    <option data-description="It's .... orange" >Orange</option>
</select>
```

To:

```
<div id="fruitselect" name="fruit" class="dd-container">
    <div class="dd-select">
        <input class="dd-selected-value" type="hidden" value="Apple">  // If I had picked Apple
        <a class="dd-selected">
            <img class="dd-selected-image" src="">  //I have images disabled for simplicity
            <label class="dd-selected-text">Apple</label>
            <small class="dd-selected-description"> It's red </small>
        </a>        
    </div>
    <ul class="dd-options">
        <li>
            <a class="dd-option dd-option-selected">
                <input class="dd-option-value" type="hidden" value="Apple" name="fruit"> // I was able to get the name here with jquery
                <img class="dd-option-image" src="">
                <label class="dd-option-text">Apple</label>
                <small class="dd-option-description"> It's red </small>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>      // another li for each other <option>
            <a class="dd-option">
            ...
            </a>
        </li>
        <li> 
            <a class="dd-option">
            ...
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The plugin works great and the images display fine. The problem is that I can't submit my `form` through PHP due to the fact that the `name` attribute isn't carried to the hidden `<input>` element.

How do I get the name from the `<select>` element in the first piece of code to the `<input class="dd-selected-value">` tag in the second piece of code. Would I do something like `$this.parentUntil("#fruitselect").attr("name")` where the plugin converts the `<select>` tag?

Another thing to consider, would it make sense to get the `name` from 2 parents up OR, perhaps, get the `name` from `<input class="dd-option-value">`

I'm new to jquery, thanks a ton!

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. If you submit the form, you should get the value of an input field with name `fruit`. No matter how it is placed in your HTML. Are you trying to get the name of the input for some other reason?

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that it was stupid to put that in. Also, I don't know why the form didn't submit something then. I guess because every `<li>` had the same name?

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you have problems with fields not being submitted OR do you need the name?

Comment: Both, nothing is submitted which is because I look for $_POST['fruit'], of which there is multiple.

Comment: I only see a single form field with that name in your example. It should be submitted as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After applying your plugin, you can simply read the "name" attribute in #fruitselect and inject it in the input tag :

```
var n = $("#fruitselect").attr("name");

$("input.dd-selected-value").attr("name", n );
```

Or in one line :

```
$("input.dd-selected-value").attr("name", $("#fruitselect").attr("name"));
```

Comment: Thanks! Alternatively how could I get the name of the element 2 parents up? `$("input.dd-selected-value").attr("name", $("input.dd-selected-value").parent().parent().attr("name"));` doesn't seem to be working. Thanks again!

Comment: Weird. It works for me... It looks correct anyway. Try $("input.dd-selected-value").closest(".dd-container").attr("name") instead of parent().parent()